# How to extract multiple tag values from multiple xml files in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

We need to extract multiple tag values from multiple files.

We have around 1000 files with data similar to:

```
<Employee>
  <Id>432361</Id>
  <EmpName>Stuart</EmpName>
  <SidNumber>0251115</SidNumber>
  <CreatedUtc>2016-11-14T22:27:53.477+08:00</CreatedUtc>
  <EpisodeId>682082</EpisodeId>
  <CorrelationId>323A6C86-76AA-E611-80DA-005056B46023</CorrelationId>
</Employee>
```

we need to extract EmpName, SidNumber and EpisodeId from all the files to a single file.
we are able to get one value at a time, for ex. using command:

```
nawk -F'[<>]' '/<EpisodeId>/{print $3}' *.dat
```

But we need to get multiple tags of each file.
the output format should be something similar to

```
EmpName Stuart SidNumber 0251115 EpisodeId 682082
EmpName Stuart SidNumber 0251115 EpisodeId 682082
```

or atleast space delimited values

```
Stuart 0251115 682082
Stuart 0251115 682082
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Vivek

Comment: do not go for `sed` or `awk`, they are not the rigth tool for the job. go for some xml aware tool like `xmllint` here is one way you should not do things , but will for fine for small xmls.
`declare $(awk -v FS='[<>]' 'length($3){print $2"="$3}' inputfile)` then `echo $EmpName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - (Created two sample files f1.txt f2.txt)

```
$ head f?.txt
==> f1.txt <==
 <Employee>
      <Id>432361</Id>
      <EmpName>Stuart</EmpName>
      <SidNumber>0251115</SidNumber>
      <CreatedUtc>2016-11-14T22:27:53.477+08:00</CreatedUtc>
      <EpisodeId>682082</EpisodeId>
      <CorrelationId>323A6C86-76AA-E611-80DA-005056B46023</CorrelationId>
   </Employee>

==> f2.txt <==
 <Employee>
      <Id>432361</Id>
      <EmpName>vipin</EmpName>
      <SidNumber>0251117</SidNumber>
      <CreatedUtc>2016-12-14T22:27:53.477+08:00</CreatedUtc>
      <EpisodeId>682082</EpisodeId>
      <CorrelationId>323A6C86-76AA-E611-80DA-005056B46023</CorrelationId>
   </Employee>
```

Processing...

```
$ for i in f?.txt;do awk -F'[<>]' '/EmpName|SidNumber|EpisodeId/{printf $3OFS} END {print ""}' $i;done
 Stuart 0251115 682082 
 vipin 0251117 682082
```

for proper formatted output -

```
$ for i in f?.txt;do awk -F'[<>]' '/EmpName|SidNumber|EpisodeId/{printf $3OFS} END {print ""}' $i;done|column -t
Stuart  0251115  682082
vipin   0251117  682082
```

if you don't have column cmd available you can try below cmd -

```
for i in f?.txt;do awk -F'[<>]' '/EmpName|SidNumber|EpisodeId/{printf "%-10s", $3OFS} END {print ""}' $i;done
Stuart    0251115   682082    
vipin     0251117   682082
```

In printf function of awk we can format the column values.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vipin, you solved my issue. If possible just one more question, in my shell for column command I am getting "bash: column: command not found". Is there any alternative to format the output.

Comment: @VivekVishal - I have updated my answer as per your need, check please.''

Comment: Thanks Vipin, really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
nawk -F'[<>]' '/<EmpName>|<SidNumber>|<EpisodeId>/{print $3}' *.dat
```

Comment: Thanks pyed, just wondering if there is a way to get a formatted output like EmpName Stuart  Stuart 0251115 EpisodeId 682082

Comment: "Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Comments would help create searchable content.
"